# How to prevent overlapping of plotLine data labels in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When the points are very close, the data labels are overlapping and I am not able to view the previous labels. I can only see the most recent data label. How do I write javascript code to view all the labels?

Code Snippet:

```
plotOptions: {
    dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    x: 5,
                    y: 10,
                    color: 'blue'
                }
     }
```

Comment: have a look in this [post](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2023) you can get workarounds

Comment: Thank you @Deep3015. It was helpful.

Comment: You can add answer which you find most useful from that post